# What ASCII characters are valid for Javascript variable names?

Tags: javascript

I've seen this other question, unfortunately the answers spend too much attention on Unicode and say nothing about normal ASCII characters.

I need to know which 7-bit ASCII characters (0..127) are valid in a Javascript identifier name.

Comment: Did you try it and see?

Comment: @epascarello: Try what exactly? Every possible combination of ASCII characters?

Comment: "the answer is too convoluted" - it's reasonably clear isn't it? True there are lots of character categories, but if you click through the links you'll see they're in code point order and many of them don't have any codes <= 0x7f, which are the ASCII codes you want.

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

Comment: Sorry, "too convoluted" is not a valid reason to post the same question yet again. There are many good answers there, does [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6671856/989121) help?

Comment: I think it's a perfectly valid question. Sure, there are thousands of Unicode characters that are allowed in theory. In practice, however, most developers will stick to ASCII identifiers, so it's great to have a succinct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp), this is all about javascript variables :

> The general rules for constructing names for variables (unique identifiers) are:
>
> Names can contain letters, digits, underscores, and dollar signs.
> Names must begin with a letter
> Names can also begin with $ and _
> Names are case sensitive (y and Y are different variables)
> Reserved words (like JavaScript keywords) cannot be used as names

You can use all ASCII codes. but you have to comply with above rules.

Comment: Nice and clear answer, thank you